# crossing the rails learning and development barrier from forms to more intesting objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've mostly been learning rails building crud applications for data entry and retrieval. I want to move on to the next level by creating an app with more interesting objects than just forms. I have been using `form_for` helper method throughout learning rails. I no longer want to create forms! My previous apps have been users signing up and writing microposts etc. I want to build a more fancy app like users creating charts for example.

Here is the idea I am trying to implement:

User's will have the ability to build dashboards. Each of the several dashboards the user can own will have various data visualization charts in them. So here is my model.

```
class Dashboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :charts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Here is the routes file:

```
resources :users do
  resources :dashboards do
    resources :comments, :chart
  end
end
```

How can I advance past the stage of dashboard_id and chart_id being displayed in view for a user? The user should be able to create dashboards and fancy charts. I know one thing for sure, I no longer need the `form_for` method. So what do I use to build such an app?

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  You've got a fine start here, but your question is very broad as currently worded.

Comment: You shouldnt use a deeper level of 2 resources.. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources Limits to nested routing

Comment: I guess my question is more view-centric. I agree it is very broad due to lack of experience in building fullstack apps. I'm a backend developer and have limited experience with front-end. I want to make a more interesting app that shows dynamic charts and graphs as part of a dashboard of a user. I have the model figured out. Right now, my pages showing basic data-enrty forms for entering and altering charts and comments belonging to dashboards that further belong to users. Sort of like edit forms. I want to make these charts and dashboards and bring em to life per user

Comment: Forms are just a way to enter data.  You can send the data via ajax in semi-interesting ways, but really you're never going to get past forms.

You'll probably want to look into javascript frameworks like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org), [BackboneJs](http://backbonejs.org/), or one listed on [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/), which demonstrates the same application across a variety of MVCs.

Comment: How about just using the `Charts` model and stack them up using html/css to render those in form of a Dashboard. Is there any particular reason you want `Dashboard` model to be up there?

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/ is very nice; some parts are commercial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can understand I think you would want to visualize your data as graphs. There are several javascript libraries that allow for data in DOM to be visualized as interactive graphs which you can manipulate too !

I personally liked  ChartJS (http://chartjs.devexpress.com/) , you might want to take a look.

All you need to do is fetch data from your models using appropriate controller and place them in the right containers ( as configured by you using ChartJS or your javascript of choice)

You make visualize data as pie charts, bar graphs, line charts etc. using the same.

Hope this answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

**Does the remainder of my design require frontend work?**

---

Yes. You need also to work with the frontend for the design of the dashboard etc...

Look into some Javascript Frameworks like [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/) , [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) or [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/), which demonstrates the same application across a variety of MVCs. as what [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791026/ben-polinsky) suggested.

Thank You !